# A question of minesweeper

Tags: minesweeper

Here is where I am. Is there a unique solution somehow?

[image: state of my mine field]

Comment: You should indicate how many bombs remain to be found.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE!

Comment: I find that a lot of minesweeper games/apps make the game more "difficult" by forcing random guesses. Those are rather annoying as I think that these should be solvable with pure logic, zero guess work.

Comment: @dcfyj I am thinking the same way. It is meant to be a pure logic game, not a probabilistic one.

Answer (score 4):

With the information given,

> there is no unique solution.
>
>  Both of the below are valid sets of mines (and there are two more, if you want to find them):
>  [image]
>  [image]

Comment: There may yet be a unique solution depending on how many mines there are; OP hasn't specified that yet.

Comment: @F1Krazy True.  There's only the one solution with 4 mines.  It's not unique with any more than that.  But that information wasn't given, so I haven't included it.

Answer (score 1):

Mnemonic has already answered your question; unfortunately there is no unique solution and you have to guess.

What I would like to point out is that your best option probability-wise is to click on one of the 10 edge squares not adjacent or diagonal to a number and work from there. The probability of a mine in those squares is between 1/10 and 1/5 whereas for the others it's between 1/3 and 2/3.

Comment: How did you know the number of bombs?

Comment: I counted 93 bombs found out of the 99 bombs on expert mode meaning 6 left.

Answer (score 1):

these are the four possible mine position combinations

> there are no "safe" squares
>
>  [image]